# how can I get the patch % data from code cov api

Tags: codecov

I am trying to do some code coverage analysis, and we enabled codecov on our opensource projec.
but I can get the following information:

1. patch % of a PR
2. the response json explaination
   anyone could help on this?
   thanks a lot in advanced
   https://docs.codecov.com/reference/repos_report_retrieve

Answer (score 0):

Tom from Codecov here. So, patch coverage inherently is between two commits. You can use the [comparison endpoint](https://docs.codecov.com/reference/repos_compare_retrieve) to get patch data.

As an example, this is the
URL (https://api.codecov.io/api/v2/github/codecov/repos/example-python/compare/?pullid=114) for pull request [114](https://github.com/codecov/example-python/pull/114) on the repo [codecov/example-python](https://github.com/codecov/example-python). Note that you may need an [API key](https://docs.codecov.com/reference/overview).

The response generated includes

```json
    "totals": {
        "patch": {
            "files": 1,
            "lines": 1,
            "hits": 1,
            "misses": 0,
            "partials": 0,
            "coverage": 100.0,
            "branches": 0,
            "methods": 0,
            "messages": 0,
            "sessions": 0,
            "complexity": 0.0,
            "complexity_total": 0.0,
            "complexity_ratio": 0,
            "diff": 0
        }
    },
```

You are looking for `totals.patch.coverage` (100.0) which matches what is shown in [Codecov](https://app.codecov.io/github/codecov/example-python/pull/114).